# Gitlab CI-CD "Operation timed out" on connection to remote server via ssh

Tags: ssh, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to setup a deploy pipeline in gitlab to my remote linux server.
The error is:

```
$ ssh -p $SERVER_PORT -i $ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP "echo 1"
ssh: connect to host myhost port myport: Operation timed out
```

The deploy (.gitlab-ci.yml) script is:

```
deploy:
  image: alpine:latest
  stage: deploy
  tags:
    - deployment
  before_script:
    - 'command -v ssh-agent >/dev/null || ( apk add --update openssh )' 
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - cat "${ID_RSA}" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add -
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
    - echo "$SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS" >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    - chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  script:
    - chmod 400 $ID_RSA
    - apk update && apk add openssh-client
    - ssh -p $SERVER_PORT -i $ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP "echo $SERVER_IP"
```

I ran the same ssh command on my local machine (with the same ID_RSA key) and it works

Answer (score 0):

> I ran the same ssh command on my local machine (with the same ID_RSA key) and it work

I often see that in my company, where a server is reachable from some clients, but not from others: network routes are not always opened to everybody.

As a diagnostic step, you can add a step in your pipeline to print the ping results to your server to check network connectivity. For instance:

```yaml
script:
    - apk add iputils
    - ping -c 4 $SERVER_IP
    - apk update && apk add openssh-client
    - ssh -p $SERVER_PORT -i $ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP "echo $SERVER_IP"
```

You can also use the command `curl -v telnet://$SERVER_IP:22`, to check the port 22 is reachable, and listening.

If it is, then check the SSH Key Permissions: You have set the permissions of the `$ID_RSA` key to 400 within the `script` section of your `.gitlab-ci.yml`.
However, since you are using the key in the `before_script` section, you might need to set the permissions before using it in the `before_script` section.

Update your `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```yaml
before_script:
    - 'command -v ssh-agent >/dev/null || ( apk add --update openssh )' 
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - chmod 400 $ID_RSA
    - cat "${ID_RSA}" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add -
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
    - echo "$SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS" >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    - chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
script:
    - apk update && apk add openssh-client
    - ssh -p $SERVER_PORT -i $ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP "echo $SERVER_IP"
```